# Need to combine two columns in a table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I need to combine two column in a table using alias name

```
select 
    firstname as fn,
    lastname as ln,
    userid,
    fn + '' + ln as fullname 
from 
    users
```

Error is

> Invalid column name 'fn'.
>   Invalid column name 'Ln'.

Comment: What is the problem you are having?

Comment: When posting a `sql` question, you should also **always** include the actual, concrete database system you're using. Not everything is covered by the SQL standard.... please add a relevant tag, like `oracle`, `mysql`, `postgresql`,  `db2`, `sql-server` or whatever else you might be using

Comment: The simple answer is that you cannot use the aliases yet, you need to use the columnnames instead, so it will have to be: firstname + ' ' + lastname as fullname ( I prefer [fullname] = [firstname] + ' ' + [lastname] but that is just my preference)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IN Sql server 2010,2012 use CONCAT(firstname , ' , ' , lastname )

2008 and lower version just use as

select firstname + '' + lastname as fullname from users.

if you alias name then

select  fn+ ' ' + ln as fullname from (
select firstname as fn, lastname as ln, userid  from users )

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT firstname as fn, 
       lastname as ln, 
       userid,
       CONCAT(firstname ,  ' , ' , lastname ) AS fullname 
FROM users
```

Comment: Tip: Code only answers without any explanation are generally frowned upon.

Answer (score 0):

This will help you

```
Select [col1] ,[col2], col1 + ' ' + col2 from table_name
```

Comment: I need to use alias name not that column name

Comment: I don't think this is applicable, can you tell me why do you want to do that?

Comment: Actually in select statement i used case statement for that i used alias name.  eg : case when Title = 'Hour' then 
  'h'
else 'd' 
end as ratefactor . This ratefactor am combining with another column